# Notation for apply operation to digits of a number

Tags: notation

what is the standard notation to represent that a operation has been applied to each digits of a number

for example

```
let x = 81
it can be said the sum of each digit is equal to the square root of x
```

a representation of this would be

$$\sum  digits = x^\frac{1}{2} $$

however would the nth digits of the number x be represented

Comment: You likely meant to say digit sum is squareroot of x, not square of x.

Comment: thank you i have edited it so the statement makes sense

Comment: Most algebraical notation is completely independent of how what base you chose to write your numbers. Hence in order to extract, say, the ten's digit of a real number $x$, you would need to do something contrieved, like use the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ and fractional part function $\{\cdot \}$ like this: $$\text{ten's digit of }x = \left\lfloor10\left\{\frac{x}{100}\right\}\right\rfloor$$Thus the sum of all digits of an integer $x$ may be written as
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left\lfloor 10\left\{\frac{x}{10^{n+1}}\right\}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: surely you could change the number 10 to other number as you change base the algebra of digits unlike most algebra is very base specific

Comment: @AlexanderRD Yes, $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left\lfloor 14\left\{\frac{x}{14^{n+1}}\right\}\right\rfloor$ would give you the sum of digits base $14$. But there is no _nice_ way to express "the sum of all digits base $10$", for the simple reason that our notion of base and decimal system isn't algebraic. It's notational. To see how little algebra and other mathematical branches care about base, take up more or less any college or graduate textbook. It would probably be possible within less than an hour to convert it to base $23$.

Comment: how would the notation of base specific operation be written in a college or graduate textbook

Comment: @AlexanderRD My point is, there _is no_ base specific notation, because mathematics itself doesn't care about base. I like to imagine it would be really difficult to actually come up with a notational system that actually was base dependent. The downside is that every time you want to do womething base dependent, you need to go out of your way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say something like:
Let $\displaystyle x=\sum_{i\mathop=0}^n a_i \times 10^i$.
Then the sum of digits is $\displaystyle \sum_{i\mathop=0}^n a_i$

---

You can also define a "sum of digits" function recursively (for positive integer only):
$\text{sum_of_digits}(x)=\begin{cases}x \text{ , if } x<10\\ \text{sum_of_digits}(\left\lfloor\dfrac x{10}\right\rfloor)+10\left\{\dfrac{x}{10}\right\}\end{cases}\text{ , otherwise}$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function and $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i\ge 1} \left\lfloor10 \{x/10^i\}\right\rfloor = \sqrt{x}$. ($\{c\}$ is the fractional part of $c$)

Thus, the n-th digit is  $\left\lfloor10 \{x/10^n\}\right\rfloor$